# Wordnet in Spanish

Tags: nlp, wordnet

Is there something similar to Princeton's WordNet in Spanish?
I need to find synonyms in Spanish.

Comment: @Hogan: yes it is, and I've retagged it into the appropriate categories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you checked here : http://www.globalwordnet.org/gwa/wordnet_table.htm ? There's a link to  a Spanish project.

Comment: There is EuroWordnet, but that project is not Open like Wordnet